# VLOOKUP/Transpose multiple IDs/search keys at once on Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, vlookup, transpose

I currently have a sheet where I can transpose a list of items from one sheet to another (rows to columns).

I was wondering if there's a way to make it so that I can pull multiple search keys/IDs at once and have it auto-populate in a column format all at once.

Currently:

1. Data Sheet tab: My item IDs (ex. "11111") and my tags for the item (ex. happy).
2. Transpose Sheet tab: If I input an ID (that exists on the "Data Sheet" tab) into A2, it'll transpose the tags for me.
3. Goal: If it's possible to input multiple item IDs at once and have it populate as shown (so transposing multiple items+their tags at once).

Maybe something like INDEX, MATCH, or a helper column, or something related to a SQL query to order by...? Thank you!

Here is the test sheet!: [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EaTnZfrdilP46tkbcVuZHD5LFU_I00zx9Fjoi0XyxtA/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: can you confirm that your example / goal is correct in your test sheet? looking eat your input dataset it doesnt make any sense

Comment: Hi! Yes, it should be correct. Currently I have my IDs w/ tags on "data sheet", and then the "transpose sheet" is where I input an ID, and it'll transpose the row data from "data sheet" once I enter an ID into A2. Since I can only transpose one ID at a time, I was wondering if there was a way where I could input multiple IDs at once and get them all transposed (the "Goal" tab)

Comment: Your input in `Goal!A2` is incorrect. Should be `111111` and `222222`.

Comment: How do you feel about using Apps Script?

Comment: I'm open to using Apps Script :o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a formula that works:

```
=query(
  {
    arrayformula(to_text('Data Sheet'!A2:A)),'Data Sheet'!B2:B;
    arrayformula(to_text('Data Sheet'!A2:A)),'Data Sheet'!C2:C;
    arrayformula(to_text('Data Sheet'!A2:A)),'Data Sheet'!D2:D;
    arrayformula(to_text('Data Sheet'!A2:A)),'Data Sheet'!E2:E;
    arrayformula(to_text('Data Sheet'!A2:A)),'Data Sheet'!F2:F
  },
  "select Col1, Col2 where Col1 is not null and Col2 is not null and (Col1='" & SUBSTITUTE(A2, ",", "' or Col1='") & "') order by Col1"
)
```

The main idea is that:

```
={
  A1:A3,B1:B3;
  A1:A3,C1:C3
}
```

will generate

```
={
  A1,B1;
  A2,B2;
  A3,B3;
  A1,C1;
  A2,C2;
  A3,C3
}
```

So to generate all the pairs you can do

```
={
  A2:A,B2:B;
  A2:A,C2:C;
  A2:A,D2;D;
  ...
}
```

Now, the values on the first column are being interpreted as numbers, so we need to transform them to text to be able to compare them. So I replaced `A2:A` with `arrayformula(to_text(A2:A))`. Then I explicitly sate the the sheet name.

Now that we have all the pairs (including empty ones) we can use query to filter them out. The first part of the filter is to remove the rows without any of the values. The second part is generated and filters for the search keys. The was this works is as follows: from `x,y,z` we need to get `(Col1='x' or Col1='y' or Col1='z')`. If we replace `,` for `' or Col1='` you can see that we get the middle part. We do that with substitute. So concatenate with the rest of the query, and we got it!

### References

- [SUBSTITUTE (Docs Editor Help article)](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094215?hl=en)
- [QUERY (Docs Editor Help article)](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en)
- [TO_TEXT (Docs Editor Help article)](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094285?hl=en)
- [ARRAYFORMULA (Docs Editor Help article)](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN('Data Sheet'!A2:A&"♦︎"&'Data Sheet'!B2:F),"♦︎"),"select * where Col2 is not null",0),CONCATENATE("select * where Col1='",JOIN("' or Col1='",SPLIT(A2,",")),"'"),0))
```